# Append SQL Tables, Union?

Tags: sql

If I have the two following tables,

Table1

```
ItemNo  Desc    Order Number    Qty      S_Date     Location
AA       AA         AAA          A     AA/AA/AAAA     AAAA
BB       BB         BBB          B     BB/BB/BBBB     BBBB
CC       CC         CCC          C     CC/CC/CCCC     CCCC
```

Table 2

```
M_Order Item    M_Date      Total
XXX      X      XX/XX/XXXX   XX
YYY      Y      YY/YY/YYYY   YY
```

Can anyone advice me how to get the following table please.

Result Table

```
ItemNo  Desc    Order Number    Qty     S_Date    Location   M_Date     Total
AA       AA        AAA           A    AA/AA/AAAA    AAAA        
BB       BB        BBB           B    BB/BB/BBBB    BBBB        
CC       CC        CCC           C    CC/CC/CCCC    CCCC        
X       XXX                                                 XX/XX/XXXX    XX
Y       YYY                                                 YY/YY/YYYY    YY
```

Thanks

Comment: USE A UNION, you can have multiple queries combined into a single result set.

Comment: I'd use UNION ALL because it's faster and UNION (in Oracle) eliminates dublicates so the result can be unexpected

Comment: @Multisync This difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL` is standard SQL, not just Oracle behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `union` and null the columns in each query that don't have values.

```
select
    ItemNo,
    Desc,
    OrderNumber,
    Qty,
    S_Date,
    Location,
    null as M_Date,
    null as Total
from Table_1
union
select
    Item,
    M_Order,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    M_Date,
    Total
from Table_2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using UNION as mentioned in the answer above, 
**provided** you have same data types for the columns you are combining

Check the following fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef709/4

Comment: I get the following error when i try to do it as above,
"Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'P053398                        ' to data type smallint."

which suggests to me that they're not in same data types.
any suggestions to resolve this??

Comment: @SanjayaWeerakkody Check the data type of the column where you have the value 'P053398' is it smallint? Then you should better change that to varchar

Comment: @SanjayaWeerakkody  OR there is another possibility, while doing union make sure that the data type of this column is same as the datatype of the column specified at the same ordinal position in select statement in another table.